# pyplot too many ticks and slow to generate

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

Im trying to log two different data types on separate Y axis using the same X index:

```
temperatureData = pd.read_csv("temperatureData.csv")
temperatureData = temperatureData.set_index('Time date')

y1_data1 = temperatureData['Temperature1']
y1_data2 = temperatureData['Temperature2']
y1_data3 = temperatureData['Temperature3']
y1_data4 = temperatureData['Temperature4']
y2_data1 = temperatureData['Vent1']
y2_data2 = temperatureData['Vent2']

x = temperatureData.index

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()  # instantiate a second axes that shares the same x-axis

ax1.set_xlabel('Date Time', color='C0')
ax1.set_ylabel('Temperatures', color='C0')
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', labelcolor='C0', labelrotation=90)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='C0')

curve1 = ax1.plot(x, y1_data1, label='Temperature1', color='tab:blue')
curve2 = ax1.plot(x, y1_data2, label='Temperature2', color='tab:orange')
curve3 = ax1.plot(x, y1_data3, label='Temperature3', color='tab:green')
curve4 = ax1.plot(x, y1_data4, label='Temperature4', color='tab:red')

ax2.set_ylabel('Open (Deg)', color='C0')
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='C0')
curve5 = ax2.plot(x, y2_data1, label='Vent1', color='r')
curve6 = ax2.plot(x, y2_data2, label='Vent2', color='b')

plt.title('Temperatures', color='C0')
plt.grid('on', linestyle='--')

plt.plot()
plt.show()
```

Now it works, however, the output takes about 5mins to generate because each of the X axis values are two weeks of data samples that have been sampled at milliseconds. So you can understand why.

Is there a way to limit the x values displayed? Is that the reason this is so slow to generate?
For example, if I run a small sample set without the following line:

```
temperatureData = temperatureData.set_index('Time date')
```

It generates the graph in: Seconds = 0.9089131355285645, but I don't get the date time values on the X axis. I only get the index number.
With that line in I get the date time values in the X axis but it takes: Seconds = 208.08867192268372

I have tried:

```
x = temperatureData['Date Time']
```

But this only generates a KeyError:'Date Time'
I feel like there is some fundumental thing about indexing that I don't understand here.

[image: example of too many x axis ticks]

Comment: Given your sampling rate and time frame, your chart would have to be 200 km long at 150 dpi to see each point. Calculate what time resolution you will need for your figure size/resolution, then downsample your data frame with pandas before plotting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I worked it out. What I had to do is use dataframes instead of individual columns:

```
temperatureData = pd.read_csv("temperatureData.csv")
temperatureData = temperatureData.set_index('Time date')
ventData = pd.read_csv("ventData.csv")
ventData = ventData.set_index('Time date')

dfTemp = temperatureData.set_index('Time date')
vents = ventData.set_index('Time date')

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax1.set_xlabel('Date Time', color='C0')
ax1.set_ylabel('Temperatures', color='C0')
ax2.set_ylabel('Vents', color='C0')
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', labelcolor='C0', labelrotation=90)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='C0')
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='C0')

curve1 = ax1.plot(dfTemp, label='Temperature supply')
curve2 = ax2.plot(vents, label='Vents')

plt.title('Temperatures', color='C0')
plt.grid('on', linestyle='--')

plt.show()
```

This now scales when I zoom in etc and it loads very quickely.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the xticks. I used another data to demonstrate, you need to set the highlighted line (second last line)

```
y1_data1 = temperatureData['TemperatureF']
y1_data2 = temperatureData['Humidity']
y2_data1 = temperatureData['Wind SpeedMPH']

x = temperatureData.index

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
ax2 = ax1.twinx()  # instantiate a second axes that shares the same x-axis

ax1.set_xlabel('Date Time', color='C0')
ax1.set_ylabel('Temperatures', color='C0')
ax1.tick_params(axis='x', labelcolor='C0', labelrotation=90)
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='C0')

curve1 = ax1.plot(x, y1_data1, label='Temperature1', color='tab:blue')
curve2 = ax1.plot(x, y1_data2, label='Temperature2', color='tab:orange')

ax2.set_ylabel('Open (Deg)', color='C0')
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='C0')
curve5 = ax2.plot(x, y2_data1, label='Vent1', color='r')

plt.title('Temperatures', color='C0')
plt.grid('on', linestyle='--')

# set ticks here
ax1.set_xticks(range(0,len(x), 100))    #set interval here

plt.show()
```

With 100 as interval
[image]

With 200 as interval
[image]

You can set interval as per your need.

Comment: Bad advice. This would still plot more than 1 billion data points (per curve) for no apparent reason.

Comment: Your solution certainly solves the problem with displaying too many X values. Thank you for this input. However, it still takes the same time to generate the data. For example, if i load the csv data into the dataframe without using set_index('Time Date') it loads almost instantly. However it doesnt show the dates on the X axis, only the index number.

Comment: Instead of setting index and doing `x = temperatureData.index` do `x = temperatureData['Time date']`

Comment: I get this unfortunately: KeyError: 'Time Date'

Comment: Mohil Patel's solution has certainly sped up the loading: Seconds: 40.968064069747925.  However, when I zoom in I loose the resolution. i.e. when I zoom in on other graphs the x-axis will scale with the zoom.